# How to add 3 validators node from different networks?

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, nodes

I want to run our substrate chain with 3 validators, and these validators will run in 3 different network.

I'm following this documentation: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/#start-the-first-node

I'm able to run successfully every commands that needs to be executed[present in the above document].

But in the log, I'm not able to see `2024-02-20 13:00:31  Idle (0 peers),`

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running node in different machines then you need to update this `127.0.0.1` to the IP where your node is running

`--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWLmrYDLoNTyTYtRdDyZLWDe1paxzxTw5RgjmHLfzW96SX \`